# Why is this javascript based calculator not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm recreating a javascript based calculator on a test site here: https://verbal-masai.jurassic.ninja/calculator/. Inspired by this site: https://thevegancalculator.com/#calculator.

So, I added the javascript and css codes to my site (attached below). I designed the page with html. But for some reason when I click '*calculate*', nothing happens. I'm pretty sure the problem is in my html which isn't referencing the js code correctly, so nothing happens. Below is the html I used for the 'months' field, the 'calculate button', and the 'gallons of water' field. If someone can point what I'm missing in html fields, I can fix the other html fields myself. Thank you.

In Chrome's Dev Tools, I see two errors but I don't know how to fix them.

Error 1:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Error 2:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: veganCalc is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick
```

Note: This page is hosted at https://jurassic.ninja, which is a is a wordpress testing site, so if you need backend access to troubleshoot, let me know and I'll provide the login info.

JS Code

```
var formatNumber = function (x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};

var kgToLb = function () {
  return v * 2.20462;
};

var lbToKg = function () {
  return v / 2.20462;
};

var gallonToLitre = function () {
  return v * 3.7854;
};

var litreToGallon = function () {
  return v / 3.7854;
};

var sqftToSqm = function () {
  return v * 0.0929;
};

var sqmToSqft = function () {
  return v / 0.0929;
};

function veganCalc () {
  var unit;
  var totalDays = 0;
  var years = $('#years').val();
  var month = $('#months').val();
  
  totalDays = (month) ? totalDays + month*30 : totalDays ;
  totalDays = (years) ? totalDays + years*365 : totalDays ;
  
  // Variables
  var indexes = {
    'gallons': {
      'ipd': {
        'imperial': 1100,
        'metric': 4163.9
      },
      'selector': '.water',
      'index': {
        'imperial': 'Gallons of water:',
        'metric': 'Litres of water:'
      }
    },
    'grains': {
      'ipd': {
        'imperial': 40,
        'metric': 18.1
      },
      'selector': '.grain',
      'index': {
        'imperial': 'lbs of Grain:',
        'metric': 'kg of Grain:'
      }
    },
    'forest': {
      'ipd': {
        'imperial': 30,
        'metric': 2.8
      },
      'selector': '.forest',
      'index': {
        'imperial': 'Sq.ft of Forest:',
        'metric': 'Sq.m of Forest:'
      }
    },
    'co2': {
      'ipd': {
        'imperial': 20,
        'metric': 9.1
      },
      'selector': '.co2',
      'index': {
        'imperial': 'lbs of Co2:',
        'metric': 'kg of Co2:'
      }
    },
    'animals': {
      'ipd': {
        'imperial': 1,
        'metric': 1
      },
      'selector': '.animals',
      'index': {
        'imperial': 'Animal Lives:',
        'metric': 'Animal Lives:'
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Functions
  var years = $('#years').val();
  var months = $('#months').val();
  var unit = $('#unit').val();
  
  //Prints
  $.map(indexes, function (v, i) {
    $(v.selector + ".index").html(v.index[unit]);
    $(v.selector + ".value").html(formatNumber( Math.round(v.ipd[unit] * totalDays) ) );
  });
  $('.intro.index').html("You have saved:");
};
```

CSS Code

```
.index.intro {
    text-align: center;
    color: #2cc03d;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-style: italic;
}

input[type="number"] {
    height: 3rem;
    background-color: #ccc;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  

   opacity: 1;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="date"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="month"], input[type="week"], input[type="email"], input[type="number"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="time"], input[type="url"], input[type="color"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: inherit;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    height: 2.3125rem;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: box-shadow 0.45s, border-color 0.45s ease-in-out;
}
.calculator .button {
    margin-top: 1.3rem;
}

.postfix, .button {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.calculator-btn {
    color: #fff;
}

.button {
    background-color: #f92f4c;
    font-size: 100%;
    height: 3rem;
    line-height: 3rem;
}

.calculator .name {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #2cc03d;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    padding: 0.3rem 1rem;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.calculator .number {
    padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    background: #1CB53D;
}
```

Months HTML

```
<label for="months">Months:</label>
<input type="number" id="months" min="0" max="12">
```

Button HTML

```
<a href="#calculator"> 
<span class="button postfix calculator-btn" onclick="veganCalc()">Calculate</span></a>
```

Gallons of water HTML

```
<div class="stat">
<div class="name box-shadow index water">Gallons of water:</div>
<div class="number value water">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Open your browser's Dev Tools/JavaScript console (usually the F12 key) and look for errors. When you click calculate: `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` Most likely your code is using jQuery syntax but you're not including the library.

Comment: Try changing your "$" to "jQuery"

Comment: Your HTML does not seem to have a years input but your JS references #years. You should be seeing an error in your browser's dev tools console if this is so.

Comment: Do you need to add 'v' as a parameter in your functions, like 'x' is in the first one? I just skimmed.

Comment: I tried changing "$" to "jQuery" in my js script. But Dev Tools also tells me there's an error in my button html 'veganCalc()'. I don't know what/how to change that. Besides, now I'm not getting this error but two new ones (listed in description above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally works! Thanks to @ugene for commenting to change $ to jQuery. After doing that, everything worked. For anyone else looking for an answer, hope this helps. WordPress comes with its own jQuery library and by default is in 'compatibility mode', so it doesn't clash with other javascript libraries. This also means that $ won't work in your script. Simply change that to jQuery and everything else will fall in place, provided your HTML is coded right.